# Hook modifier stretches unselected vertices

Tags: modifiers

I set up a door and want to the width (Breite), height (Höhe) and opening (Winkel) using empties on hook modifiers.
The opening of the door and modifying the height by manipulating the empties works nice.
But when I want to put variation on the width not only the frame of the door moves but the whole door panel moves and stretches.

What's wrong?

[image]

Comment: Anybody? No ideas how to solve my problem? Other ways?